# UINavigationItem Transparency

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a `UINavigationItem` (not a `UINavigationBar`) that I would like to make transparent or not opaque. This gets created when I make a relationship segue root view controller from a Navigation Controller to my `UIViewController` subclass.

I tried to embed it in a `UINavigationBar`, but couldn't make that work. There do not appear to be any methods for `UINavigationItem` that would allow me to change the appearance of its background.

Is there any way to accomplish this, either by embedding it inside a view of some sort or by getting a pointer to some object that has this capability?

Here is the storyboard that shows the hierarchy of the view controller. You can see the `UINavigationItem` as a direct descendant of the view controller. Notice that there is no explicit reference to a `UINavigationBar`:

[image]

Here is an image of the navigation section at the top of my `UIViewController` when it renders. I'd like to change the light gray to match the dark gray that you can see just below it:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs:

> In iOS 5.0 and later, you can customize the appearance of the bar using the methods listed in Customizing the Bar Appearance. You can customize the appearance of all navigation bars using the appearance proxy ([UINavigationBar appearance]), or just of a single bar.
>
> In iOS 7, a navigation bar’s tintColor affects the color of the back indicator image, button titles, and button images. The barTintColor property affects the color of the bar itself. Additionally, navigation bars are translucent by default. Turning the translucency off or on does not affect buttons, since they do not have backgrounds.

Comment: My dilemma is that I don't have an explicit `UINavigationBar` (see the storyboard image in my post). If I had a reference to the bar, I would be all set. Do you know how I can get a reference to the bar?

Comment: Your view controller is inside a `UINavigationController`, right? So from your content view controller it will be `self.navigationController.navigationBar`.

Comment: `self.navigationControoler.navigationBar` was exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks very much!